# Looking for a word to describe several short discussions or presentations in a row

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Let's say you attend a presentation, but instead of a single presenter, you have several presenters come up one right after the other in succession, each with their own (but related) topic. Can this be described with a single word? Kind of like speed dating but for presentations.

For example:

"For our meeting on Monday we'll have a [series of short but related] presentations on such-and-such topic. Let me know who'd like to participate."

Comment: rapid-fire presentation?

Comment: Consider this idea: Within the context of cinema (and possibly theatre) there are 2 words *ensemble* and *portmaneau* which refer to many short, related pieces or story-lines that are assembled creatively into a united production. Please look up their proper meanings in a standard dictionary or a glossary of film / theatrical terms.

Comment: Short takes on a single subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are words that mean exactly this.

1. [Symposium](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/symposium)

> A formal meeting at which several specialists deliver short addresses
>   on a topic or on related topics

2. [Colloquium](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colloquium)

> A usually academic meeting at which specialists deliver addresses on a
>   topic or on related topics and then answer questions relating to them

In my experience both these words are primarily used in an academic setting, but I don't see any reason why they couldn't be used more generally.

Comment: A very good answer - upvote - short and simple; exactly solves OP's problem!

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Talks -- In many professional conference presentations there are sessions called Lightning Talks. I belong to the Society for Technical Communication and we have one of these sessions at each of our conferences (Summit). They are very popular with attendees and speakers because they force the speaker to make their topic clear and to the point and makes the attendees listen more attentively. A lightning talk is generally a 5 minute presentation and may include performances, slides, audience participation, etc. Another benefit of a Lightning Talk session is that it lets more speakers participate at a conference.

For additional information about Lightning Talks, see the Wikipedia entry at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_talk